# If a rational preference relation over simple lotteries $\succsim$ are convex then they satisfy independence?

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory, preferences, decision-theory, discrete-preferences

Let´s say there is an uncertain situation with $N$ possible consequences $C = \{C_1, . . . C_N\}$. Assume that
there is a rational preference relation $\succsim$  over simple lotteries.

I know that if $\succsim$ satisfies independence, then it is also **convex**, but is it true if $\succsim$ are convex then they satisfy independence? How can I show this (if the implication is true)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It's well known that if $\succsim$ satisfies independence, then it is also **convex**.

Since $\succsim$ satisfies independence,
$L\succsim L^{'} \iff \alpha L+(1-\alpha)L^{''}\succsim \alpha L^{'}+(1-\alpha)L^{''}$ for all $\alpha \in [0,1]$ and $ L, L^{'}, L^{''}\in \mathfrak{L} $

Convexity requires:

$L\succsim L^{''}$ and  $L^{'}\succsim L^{''} \Longrightarrow \alpha L$ + $(1-\alpha)L^{'} \succsim L^{''}$ for all $\alpha \in \left[0,1\right]$  and $ L, L^{'}, L^{''}\in \mathfrak{L} $

Pick any $ L, L^{'}, L^{''}\in \mathfrak{L} $  with $L \succsim L^{''}$  and $L^{'} \succsim L^{''}$. By completeness, $L \succsim L^{'}$ or $L^{'} \succsim L$ or both. Without loss of generality, assume $L \succsim L^{'}$. Then, by independence, for all $\alpha \in [0,1]:$

$ \alpha L$ + $( 1- \alpha) L^{'} \succsim \alpha L^{'} + (1-\alpha)L^{'}  = L^{'} \succsim L^{''} $, which we wanted to show.

2. Is it true if $\succsim$ are convex then they satisfy independence?

On the other side, convexity does not imply independence. To see this, take a look
at Figure (see below). Triangles are indifference curves and arrows show the direction in which
utility increases. It is convex, but not independent.

[image]